# Can i convert an attribute from active record from Big Decimal to Integer?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an attribute coming back from Active Record that is a Big Decimal. The database column's data is numeric(18,0) and I'm not authorized to change it. i would like to be able to convert the attribute into an Integer with no decimal precision, but i'm not having any luck. I know that I can convert the value into something else by using big_decimal.to_i, however I am hoping there is a way to handle this within the Active Record Model possibly after_initialize so that I don't have to worry about conversion anywhere else in my code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're stuck with a legacy schema you can always work around that by adding a wrapper method:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def int_column
    value = read_attribute(:big_decimal)

    # Preserve `nil` values and avoid converting to zero.
    value and value.to_i
  end

  def int_column=(value)
    write_attribute(:big_decimal, value)
  end
end
```

That gives you a method for reading/writing from that column using an alternate name.

Answer (score 1):

You can always alias the current method and then override it.

Let's say the attribute is charge

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  # right now #charge returns #<BigDecimal:7fb6c285fe28,'0.0',9(18)>

  # now we can alias the current method #charge
  alias_method :big_decimal_charge, :charge

  # now they both return #<BigDecimal:7fb6c285fe28,'0.0',9(18)>
  # and we can redefine #charge, based on the alias

  def charge
    big_decimal_charge.to_i
  end

end
```

I wouldn't imagine there would be a need to change the setter.